# How do I turn off notifications from the home screen of my iPhone in iOS 9?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

How do I turn off the notification on the lower left corner? I tried to turn off notifications in Settings for the app, but it didn't work. iOS 9.0.2.

[image: notification on lower left]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not notifications, those are apps that are suggested by iOS due to location and usage, or by Handoff from your other devices.

To change the settings for those, change the toggles in `General > Handoff & Suggested Apps` in the `Settings` app. Toggle everything off if you do not use Handoff and do not want to see any suggestions.

[image]